# Fedora 33 shutdown takes a very long time

Tags: fedora, reboot

I have installed Fedora 33 Workstation 64-bit to a HDD, the HDD is Seagate Exos 7E8 ST4000NM000A, as its capacity is over 2TiB it is partitioned GPT-style, but I have created a 1MiB BIOS boot partition at the very beginning of the HDD, the layout of the HDD is as follows:

```
No. label       mountpoint      size    filesystem

0   biosboot    "BIOS_grub"     1MiB    "BIOS Boot"
1   boot        /boot           500MiB  EXT4
2   root        /               20GiB   EXT4
3   home        /home           600GiB  EXT4
4   var         /var            16GiB   EXT4
5   swap        N/A             16GiB   swap
6   Tremillia   N/A             3TiB    NTFS
```

My computer's motherboard is BIOSTAR H81MHv3, my CPU is Intel Core i5-4430 @3GHz, the GPU is NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1050 Ti, with 16GiB (2*8GiB) Kingston DDR3 1600MHz RAM.

I have not encountered any issue with booting, Fedora boots pretty fast, about 15 to 30 seconds, I don't know, I haven't measured it, but the shutdown process takes a long time, it can take up to several minutes, again I haven't measured it, but it really takes that long.

This doesn't happen every time I shutdown or restart, but at least once every three times, I don't know what might have caused the issue, and I am fairly new to Linux so I can't provide any further details now, what might have caused this issue, what steps should I take to diagnose it and how can I solve it?

---

***Update***

I am really new to Linux and there is too much information, I don't know what I should be looking for, I redirected the whole output of `journalctl` command to a txt file and uploaded to Google Drive:

[`journalctl` dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W7TW40FQD-Nzm_m47reVajIBJVd1EGtI/view?usp=sharing)

---

**Update**

Hmm, that seems to be it, `PackageKit` seems to be the culprit, I do remember I have updated all installed programs, and after that shutdown hangs.

Now that the cause is identified, how do I solve it? What tweak should I make to fix this bug? I don't want Fedora shutdown to hang every time I install new programs.

Comment: Check `journalctl` output.

Comment: Looks like it's `PackageKit` ignoring `SIGTERM` during shutdown.  You can see the [Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1717185) for more details and some possible mitigations.